# How do I remove fadeIn?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I'm working on a simple landing page. I have a jquery file but i dont really know how to hide the fade. I mean i just want to animate the 5 image without fade. What do u think where is the probelm ?

http://yourjavascript.com/13873144111/jquery.js - jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".start").click(function() {
            $.when($('.start2').fadeIn(2000)).done(function() {
                $.when($('.start3').fadeIn(2000)).done(function() {
                    $.when($('.start4').fadeIn(2000)).done(function() {
                        $.when($('.start5').fadeIn(3000)).done(function() {
                            $(".start").hide();
                            setTimeout(function()
                            {
                                $(".start").fadeIn(2000);
                                $(".start2, .start3, .start4, .start5").hide();
                            }, 3000);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
   });
```

Comment: What do you mean with "animate without the fade"? The animation *is* the fade.

Comment: than without animation. just a simple picture after picture.

Comment: Just do `show()` and `hide()` Can you provide the html or create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: If my answer was of any help, please, consider accepting it as your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's something you don't understand, you're actually using the `fadeIn` animation, so to 'Hide' it, like you asked you have to actually not use it. If you want the stuffs to appear with no fading, you can either use [`slideDown`](https://www.google.ht/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fslidedown%2F&ei=UV_rU9uzCui-sQSi84KQDw&usg=AFQjCNFTXGeKEs21P4-ZXMwwROtFtwXEWw&bvm=bv.72938740,d.cWc), your own [`.animate`](https://www.google.ht/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fanimate%2F&ei=WF_rU-yQLcHIsATFvoHACg&usg=AFQjCNEbtYj_CVrTF4Rx7m_-wysrfpbSQw&bvm=bv.72938740,d.cWc) to create custom animation or [`show`](https://www.google.ht/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fshow%2F&ei=VV_rU5nyI9DgsATAiIDoDg&usg=AFQjCNHOVPL0N8oUECD1DYHnl6J3lfq6qA&bvm=bv.72938740,d.cWc) instead of `fadeIn`.

So to simply use `slideDown`, you would do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
        $(".start").click(function()
        {
            $.when($('.start2').slideDown(2000)).done(function() {
                $.when($('.start3').slideDown(2000)).done(function() {
                    $.when($('.start4').slideDown(2000)).done(function() {
                        $.when($('.start5').slideDown(3000)).done(function() {
                            $(".start").hide();
                            setTimeout(function()
                            {
                                $(".start").slideDown(2000);
                                $(".start2, .start3, .start4, .start5").hide();
                            }, 3000);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });

   });


  </script>
```

And maybe use [`slideUp`](https://www.google.ht/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fslideup%2F&ei=x1_rU8qfBa7LsASU7IIo&usg=AFQjCNFtEyzOpnezlMJ3GDIzFm-pV7ATsg&bvm=bv.72938740,d.cWc) instead of `hide`

Comment: Then use `show` or `animate` as I suggested. @pearcider

Comment: hmm i dont really understand how :/

Comment: @pearcider [Here it is using `slideDown`](http://jsfiddle.net/0h7et3k5/2/) But if you want my opinion, using `fadeIn` looks better.

Comment: so i would like something like this: http://gifmaker.cc/PlayGIFAnimation.php?folder=2014081322GEgJQ2kkeVkBsOMlRWTx5t&file=output_Q8BsJn.gif

Comment: @pearcider Then you can use [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) like so: http://jsfiddle.net/d88xe2tw/

Comment: god bless u :D i found your website can i write a message u ? i have one more question :)

Comment: @pearcider Sure. contact me at nick@rameau.me

Comment: @pearcider I received nothing from you.